# R microbenchmark and autoplot?

Tags: r, microbenchmark

I have a couple of questions about microbenchmark and autoplot

Suppose this is my code:

```
library("ggplot2")
tm <- microbenchmark(rchisq(100, 0),rchisq(100, 1),rchisq(100, 2),rchisq(100, 3),rchisq(100, 5), times=1000L)
autoplot(tm)
```

1. What are the units in tm$time? how can i convert that to seconds?
2. How can I change the marks on the x axis to something like seq(from=0, to=100,by = 5)?

Thanks!

Comment: Really should be one question per post here by the way....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`help(microbenchmark)` gives:

```
1.  ‘time’ is the measured execution time
    of the expression in nanoseconds.
```

**NANOseconds** not milliseconds or microseconds.

So divide by 1000000000 to convert to seconds.

And for your second question, my first response is "why?". But its ggplot-based, so you can override bits by adding ggplot things:

```
 autoplot(tm) + scale_y_log10(name="seq(whatever)")
```

Note the plot is rotated so the x-axis is the y-scale....

I've just thought you really mean "tick marks"? Slightly different but doable, but not really appropriate given the log axis. You can force a non-log axis with specified tick marks:

```
 autoplot(tm) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,10000,len=5),name="not a log scale")
```

You can keep the log scale and set the tick mark points:

```
 autoplot(tm) + scale_y_log10(breaks=c(50,200,500))
```

Comment: can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65458335/r-using-microbenchmark-and-ggplot2-to-plot-runtimes thanks